# How to set back not up button on Actionbar

Tags: android

I have `AlbumListActivity`, I am fetching list of albums from internet. When album on the list is clicked, user is taken to `AlbumDetailActivity`. In `AlbumDetailActivity` when I press phone's back button, it takes me back to `AlbumListActivity` and when I press back button on ActionBar it again takes me back to `AlbumlistActivity` but reloading data in the list. I red this [post](https://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/ancestral-temporal) and I understand that Back and Up are different things. But in this case it really does not matter because `AlbumDetailActivity` will not be open by another application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on pressing the Up button, just call the

> onBackPressed()

method like so:

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```